# gulp plugin - to merge broken js files into one js file?

Tags: javascript, gulp, javascript-objects

I have read all the answers on the internet that I could find on this subject in last two days. Now I am just searching for gulp plugin that can merge broken js files into one big js file and not to throw error in terminal caused by unclosed function in one js file.

Explanation:

I have created js app built with modules.
At the very beginning I didn't knew that this will become big app and therefore I have wrote js code in one file.

Now I have come to an idea to split app.js file like this:

**app-start.js** (Named IIFE function open)

module1.js

module2.js

etc.

**app-end.js**  (Named IIFE function closed)

I am using gulp as task runner and gulp-concat which works perfectly.

Problem is that when I try to break IIFE function in two files (app-start.js, app-end.js) then gulp doesn't wanna build bundle.js file.
I get error in terminal that I should repair my js code in
app-start.js

So, my question is,
do You maybe know about gulp plugin that will merge multiple js files in given order and never mind the js code errors in those files?

This is my gulp.js code:

```
    var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
    sourceMap = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    babel = require('gulp-babel');



    gulp.task('sass', function() {
    gulp.src('resources/sass/config-normalize.sass')
    //.pipe(sourceMap.init())
    .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 30 versions']}))
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'expanded'})) //expanded - compressed  
    //.pipe(sourceMap.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('configurator/css'));

    gulp.src('resources/sass/config-style.sass')
    //.pipe(sourceMap.init())
    .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 30 versions']}))
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'expanded'})) //expanded - compressed  
    //.pipe(sourceMap.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('configurator/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});


gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    gulp.src([
        //'resources/js/vendor/jquery.js',
        //'resources/js/vendor/library/neki_file.js',
        'resources/js/001-app-start.js',          
        'resources/js/002-ajax.js',
        'resources/js/003-global-variables.js',

        'resources/js/050-main.js',

        'resources/js/100-my-modules.js',
        'resources/js/app-end.js'
        ])
    //.pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['es2015']
        }))
    .pipe(concat('all.js'))
    //.pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('configurator/js'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});



gulp.task('php', function() {
    gulp.src('./**/*.php')
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});




gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: "localhost"     //Upisi path do projekta na local hostu bez http://
    });
});




gulp.task('images', function() {
    return gulp.src('assets/images-uncompressed/**/*')
        .pipe(imagemin({
            progressive: true,
            svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
            use: [pngquant()]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/images'));
});



gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('./**/*.php', ['php']);
    gulp.watch('resources/sass/**', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('resources/js/**', ['scripts']);
    //gulp.watch('resources/images-uncompressed/*', ['images']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'scripts', 'php', 'browser-sync', 'watch']);
```

Comment: You should _really_ refactor your code so that each file is syntactically valid JavaScript. You'll find that basically no tools will work with this approach.

Comment: I am aware of that and that is my last option which comes right after I try this. Also I have other ways to test this js code in the end and therefore testing js in build process is not so important to me for this project.

Comment: Running `gulp-concat` before any JavaScript-aware task should work, however. Can you post your Gulp script?

Comment: I have added my gulp code to my message.

Comment: Run `concat` (which doesn't need to understand JavaScript) before `babel` (which does).

Comment: I see, let me try that, it will take some time.

Comment: Hey joews It is working properly, just as You said it will.
Please make this as your answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the order you run your Gulp tasks:

`babel` parses and transforms JavaScript so it needs well-formed input.

`concat` doesn't need to understand JavaScript; it just combines text files. It will happily deal with your broken-up files.

If you move `concat` before `babel`, Babel can work on a single, well-formed blob of JavaScript built up from your split files.

Comment: Thank You joews for resolving this!